# Static constexpr function defined with literal

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

I know that there is way of variadic recursion for compile time calculations, and we also can call lambda functions with some nesting depth in compile time, but what if I want to combine these cases together? What is exactly the problem in second case? I still using lamda literals.

```
constexpr int pow (int a) {
    return a * a;
} 

constexpr auto lambda() -> std::function<int(int)> { // invalid return type
    return  [] (int a) {return a * a; };
}

class A {
public:
    static constexpr int foo(int a) {return a * a;};
    static constexpr std::function<int(int)> bar1 = lambda();
    static constexpr std::function<int(int)> bar2 = [] (int a) {return a * a; };
    A() = default;
}
// error: the type ‘const std::function<int(int)>’ of ‘constexpr’ variable ‘A::bar1’ is not literal
// static constexpr std::function<int(int)> f = [] (int a) {return a * a;}
// same with bar2

int main() {
 
    static_assert(pow(2) == 4, "Runtime"); // works

    constexpr auto add = [](int n, int m) { // works
        auto L = [=] {return n; };
        auto R = [=] {return m; };
        return[=] {return L() + R(); };
    };
    static_assert(add(3, 4)() == 7, "Runtime"); // works

    static_assert([](){}, "Runtime"); // works

    static_assert(A::foo(2), "Runtime"); // works
    static_assert(A::bar1(2), "Runtime"); // error
    static_assert(A::bar2(2), "Runtime"); // error

    // 1. the type ‘const std::function<int(int)>’ of ‘constexpr’ variable ‘A::f’ is not literal
    // static constexpr std::function<int(int)> f = [] (int a) {return a * a;}

}
```

Comment: The compiler told you exactly what the problem is: `std::function<int(int)>` is not a [literal type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType)

Comment: But this is literal: "[] (int a) {return a * a;}", I put it also in main function static assert check, and static assert dont't mark it as problem;

Comment: @SergeyInozemcev: That's correct.  It is the type erasure to `std::function` that is incompatible

Comment: bar2 also do not compile even if I use literal right in declaration

Comment: What's wrong with `static constexpr int bar2(int a) { return a * a; }` ?

Comment: @SergeyInozemcev I think you're confused by what is meant by literal in this context. _Literal_ doesn't refer to a type of expression (as you appear to be using it). It refers to a _named requirement_ for a specific category of types. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Off topic: `bar1` can't be `int`

Comment: Could you comment on why you want to convert the lambdas to `std::function`s? Is there anything wrong with using the anonymous closure types themselves? E.g., `constexpr auto lambda() { return ... }`. Unlike `std::function`, closure types _are_ literal types.

Comment: @max66 yes, you right, sorry, But anyway don't work even with std::function<int(int)>

Comment: @Brian  I want to repeat the functionality with a call lambda functions nested within each other, but pack it into some kind of class. To be able to configure this nesting.

Comment: @SergeyInozemcev - Sorry but isn't clear, for me, what do you exactly want. Please, can you add an example of use?

Comment: I work on Anyproccessor object, it can combine some algebra terms in one reduce calculation. It works at runtime but I playing around  make same thing compile time. This is example of usage: https://github.com/officefish/StudingTemplates/blob/master/StudingTemplates/StudingTemplates.cpp

Comment: Not sure... do you want to develop a `lambda()`/`overload_lambda` that can be `constexpr`? Anyway... what's wrong with `auto`? I mean: what about simply `constexpr auto lambda() { return  [] (int a) {return a * a; }; }` and `class A { public: static constexpr auto bar = lambda(); };`

Comment: @max66 You right, this variant works:  "static constexpr int foo(int a) {return a * a;};" so I should work with this type of declarations. I just interest is it my fault or it is c++ limitation.

Comment: The `std::function` `constexpr` problem is a C++ limitation. Or better: it's a limitation of the template class `std::function`: [as you can see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), there isn't a `constexpr` constructor.